# how to download full Athena query result to CSV file

Tags: csv, download, truncate

In my Athena query result, there is a string column with value like '997767522.1634074402'. When I downloaded the query result to a CSV file, the value of this column was truncated to '997767522.16'. How to download the full string but not truncated?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably the csv viewer(excel or something similar) will be displaying them as you see - open the file in text editor and see the actual value.